# Creating large dual-port RAM in VHDL

Tags: memory, vhdl, ram, fpga

I am trying to generate a RAM to store an editable bitmap for a rudimentary paint program in VHDL. To do this, one set of I/O takes the address of the current pixel and outputs the stored pixel color. The other set takes the address of the pixel to be written and the color for its data input. Because of the size of the display, this needs to be a 1Megx12bit dual-port RAM. However, synthesis infers latches starting exactly at the 2^13th address leading me to believe I am running out of resources. What can I do to get this RAM to work?

Here's the code (note that the input tool is not used and will eventually be removed):

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity DUALRAM_Custom is port (
    ADDR1  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(19 downto 0);
    D_in2  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
    ADDR2  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(19 downto 0);
    WE2    : in  STD_LOGIC;
    tool   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    CLR    : in  STD_LOGIC;
    CLK    : in  STD_LOGIC;
    D_out1 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0)
);      
end DUALRAM_Custom;

architecture Behavioral of DUALRAM_Custom is
    type RAM_type is ARRAY(0 to 1048575) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
    signal RAM : RAM_type := (others => (others => '0'));
begin

    process(CLK) is
    begin
        if((CLK'event) AND (CLK = '1')) THEN
            D_out1 <= RAM(to_integer(unsigned(ADDR1)));

            if ((WE2 = '1') AND (CLR = '0')) THEN
                if (CLR = '1') THEN
                    RAM(to_integer(unsigned(ADDR2))) <= x"000";
                else
                    RAM(to_integer(unsigned(ADDR2))) <= D_in2;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: I don't see any latches in the code you've shown. That being said, your `CLR` won't work properly.

Comment: Does your target platform support 1,5 MiB of BlockRAM? Normally, an external (S)SRAM is more suitable for such a pixel buffer.

Comment: Bill - my CLR is supposed to set the active address to 0 - it's more of an erase than a clear.

Paebbels - I am uncertain. I'll try to use CoreGen that comes with Xilinx and see if it allows a larger dual block RAM because I think distributed RAM is limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at exactly what type of RAM your parts support.  One thing that is may be causing problems is the initialization of the RAM.  Some technologies do not support reset on their RAMs.  Some will as a pre-load during power up.

```
signal RAM : RAM_type := (others => (others => '0'));
```

Also note that your CLR logic is a little odd (as noted by Bill Lynch).  Note that the functional part of a RAM on your chip probably does not have any form of reset on it, so this would be extra logic on the front end of your RAM.  Mix that in with your coding style and it might result in something that your synthesis tool will not support.  I would recommend at least temporarily removing the CLR functionality, get it working without it and experiment with re-adding it.

I also recommend using a variable for your RAM rather than a signal as a signal for a RAM of the size you are implementing may result in your simulation running much slower than a variable.

The following code is for a true dual port RAM.  I have synthesized this for both Xilinx and Altera.  It has a little more features than you need, so remove the parts you don't need and give it a try.  It may take a little experimenting to get to the tools synthesizing exactly what you want.

```
architecture RTL of DPRam_RIRO_RF_1024_var is
begin
  MemProc : process (ClkA, ClkB) 
    type MemType is array (0 to 1023) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) ;
    variable Mem : MemType ;
  begin
    if rising_edge(ClkA) then     
      DataOutA <= Mem(to_integer(unsigned(AddrA))) ; 
      if WriteA = '1' then 
        Mem(to_integer(unsigned(AddrA))) := DataInA ; 
      end if ;
    end if ;

    if rising_edge(ClkB) then     
      DataOutB <= Mem(to_integer(unsigned(AddrB))) ; 
      if WriteB = '1' then 
        Mem(to_integer(unsigned(AddrB))) := DataInB ; 
      end if ;
    end if ;

  end process ; 
end RTL ;
```

Once you get something that works, be sure to look at how many resources it uses as I have noticed that some of my working RAMs ended up using 2X the resources I needed until I got the coding right.

Comment: Jim - I generated a larger RAM using CoreGen and I'm pretty sure it fixed the problem I had, but now I'm using 130% of available RAMB36E1 blocks in my Nexys4 board. I'm going to have to rethink my design.

Comment: I would expect CoreGen to do as good as possible for this, so looks like you may have used too much RAM for the chip you have.  When possible, I usually try to avoid using the wizards/CoreGen - that way I have a circuit that is portable between different technologies, however, one place where code can be problematic is with RAMs - and much more than philosophy, I finishing my project.

Comment: I have been able to make the RAM and I'll post how if others have this issue. Instead of adding exactly 2^20 address blocks to use, I entered in exactly as many as I needed, and now I am significantly under budget for RAM blocks. So I guess if this small detail is overlooked, people can be implementing RAM that is far larger than what they need.